# CSS transition values in "from" and "to" states

Tags: css, css-transitions, specifications, browser-support

I've been trying to use a `transition-delay` when moving from "state A" to "state B" but not having that delay when moving back to state A. This is a general question though about whether the CSS spec says that the settings for a transition should be those when the transition starts or those from the state which is being transitioned to. Here is an example:

```
.menu {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

.menu.is-open{
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 5s ease-out;
}
```

Should the opening animation animation take 1 second or 5 seconds?

My code is slightly more complicated as it uses a delay, but basically it boils down to this.

```
.menu {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out 0;
}

.menu.is-open {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
}
```

When I try this in Chrome or Firefox I get a delay when opening the menu and no delay when closing the menu, but in IE11/Edge it behaves as it would without the delay set. So I'm not sure whether this is a browser bug, or whether I've misunderstood how transitions work, hence my more general question about which transitions are used.

Comment: just to clarify, you want the following: 1. from menu to open menu: [no-delay][transition over a period of half a second] 2. from open menu to closed menu: [half second delay][half second transition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `transition: transform` and not `transition: translate`
The transition rule accepts CSS properties not values

---

Try reversing the order so that the `.menu` gets the half second delay

```
.menu{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: transform 0.5s 0.5s ease-out;
}

.menu.is-open{
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s 0s ease-out;
}
```

As for not working in IE, see [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) for `transition` and `transform`

Comment: Sorry, yes that's a mistake in my example, I'll reword it.

Comment: @jonhobbs did reversing the order helped? @Aziz you can't use only `0` for [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay), it should be `0s`.

Comment: I think I may have had it in the wrong order but I was already using 0s instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you understood correctly how [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transition) works. See my code snippet:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/u2q2xt8m/4/)

```css
.hoverable {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.moving {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s linear 0s;
    transition: -ms-transform 1s linear 0s;
    transition: transform 1s linear 0s;
}

.hoverable:hover + .moving {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(200%);
    transform: translateX(200%);
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s linear 0.5s;
    transition: -ms-transform 0.5s linear 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverable">Hover me</div>
<div class="moving">I can move</div>
```

Maybe [`transition-timing-function: ease-out`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) seems like [delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) for you in some cases, so I used `transition-timing-function: linear` in my example to show the transition with a constant speed.

The red block moves from `0%` to `200%` for `0.5s` with `0.5s` delay. And moves from `200%` to `0%` for `1s` without delay. There is no any magic with how [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transition) works.